# Replacing schema name when sharing sql script with other users

Tags: postgresql

When collaborating with colleagues I need to change the schema name every time I receive a SQL script (Postgres).

I am only an ordinary user of a corporate database (no permissions to change anything). Also, we are not allowed to create tables in `PUBLIC` schema. However, we can use (read-only) all the tables from `BASE` schema.

It is cumbersome for the team of users, where everybody is creating SQL scripts (mostly only for creating tables), which need to be shared amongst others. Every user has its own schema.

Is it possible to change the script below, where I will share the script to another user without the need for the other user to find/replace the schema, in this case, `user1`?

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user1.table1;

CREATE TABLE user1.table1 AS
SELECT * FROM base.table1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the default schema at the start of the script (similar to what `pg_dump` generates):

```
set search_path = user1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;

CREATE TABLE table1 AS
SELECT * FROM base.table1;
```

Because the [search path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) was change to contain `user1` as the first schema, tables will be searched in that schema when dropping and creating. And because the search path does not include any other schema, no other schema will be consulted.

If you

---

However the default `search_path` is `"$user", public` which means that any unqualified table will be searched or created in a schema with the same name as the current user.

#### Caution

Note that a `DROP TABLE` will drop the table in the first schema found in that case. So if `table1` doesn't exist in the user's schema, but in the public schema, it would be dropped from the public schema. So for your use-case setting the path to exactly one schema might be more secure.